# Does a SetProcessor require dynamic mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch

When using a SetProcessor to enrich documents with a new field, what is the behavior if strict mapping is used for the index? Does the field being set by the SetProcessor need to be added to the mapping beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the new field needs to be added to the mapping prior to the execution of the pipeline. It makes no difference if you just add a new field to your source document or if an ingest pipeline creates one out of the blue, strict mapping is strict, no matter what.